# Please help me finding Errors In this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I have encountered an error in the below codes.
I am trying to print each 'Rating' in an array, but it is not working.

````
PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]
i = 0
Rating = PlayListRatings[0]

While (i < len(PlayListRatings) and Rating >= 6) :
    Rating = PlayListRatings [i]
    print(Rating)
    i=i+1
    ```
````

Comment: I see syntax and indentation errors.

Comment: ...and capitalisation errors. Please describe what errors you are seeing.

Comment: Tell us what when wrong and especially make sure the code you post actually demonstrates the error. If you copy this code you'll see it fails with a syntax error. If that's your problem, you should include the traceback error message so we can see that too.

Comment: Your question is too general. Please be more specific and write what exactly does not work and what is your error.

Answer (score 1):

I think error is coming because of capitalization of the keyword "While". In python, keywords 'while' do not have any capitals in it.
Try rewriting the code in this format:

```
PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]
i = 0 
Rating = PlayListRatings[0]
while(i < len(PlayListRatings) and Rating >= 6):
  Rating = PlayListRatings [i] 
  print(Rating) 
  i=i+1
```

This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

your question and code are a bit confusing to me. You said you want to print all ratings in the array? If so, then why do you need the second condition?!! Just use a normal foreach loop as follows:

```
PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]
for each_value in PlayListRatings:
    print(each_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword while in your code should not be "While". Try this-

```
PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]
i = 0 
Rating = PlayListRatings[0]

while (i < len(PlayListRatings) and Rating >= 6): 
    Rating = PlayListRatings [i] 
    print(Rating) 
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Test it in [this sandbox.](https://edube.org/sandbox)

What you are doing wrong is checking if the number is greater than/ equal to `6` in a `while` loop. what this means is, as soon `Rating` is less than `6`, the loop will stop.

Secondly, you initialize `Rating` as the first element of your array.
How you had the loop set tout meant that on the first loop, array[0] gets printed, and `i` is 0. then `Rating` gets set t be array[i], **then** i gets incremented.
The next time the loop goes, that means that array[0] will be printed again.

Lastly you use `While` instead of `while`. Syntax in python is case sensitive, so be careful of where you put capitals.

```
PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]
i = 0
Rating = 0
while(i < len(PlayListRatings)):
    Rating = PlayListRatings [i]
    if(Rating >= 6):
        print(Rating)
    i=i+1
```

Comment: `if` is not a function. You can drop the parantheses in `if(Rating >= 6):` and write `if Rating >= 6:` instead.

Comment: @Matthias strange, it still provided an execution in a sandbox :/.
Anyway, I appreciate the heads up, it's been a while since I'd left c# for python